# Protractor- check whether a element is next to another element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, protractor

I need to check through protractor whether a element is next to another element or not.
 here I have a button as "Save ", I have to check whether "Cancel" button is displayed on the right of it or not.How do I check this.

Comment: I am not sure if this a good idea to test such a thing using Protractor!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use getLocation:

```
element(by.id('someId')).getLocation().then(loc) {
  console.log(loc.x, loc.y);
};
```

and compare both buttons values. But as Sakshi Singla mentioned, protractor normaly is used to simulate a users behaviour in a browser, not to test layouts.

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean how to test an HTML markup, not the actual visual layout. 
If I understand you correctly, then there are multiple ways to do it.

I would get the button group/container and assert the list of buttons inside.

Example (using [`element.all()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder) and [`map()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.map)):

```
var buttons = element.all(by.css('.btn-group button')).map(function (elm) {
    return elm.getText();
});

expect(buttons).toEqual(['Save', 'Cancel']);
```

---

Or, if you found the `Save` button, you can check the *following sibling* using [`by.xpath()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.By.xpath):

```
var save = element(by.css('button.btn-save'));
var cancel = save.element(by.xpath('following-sibling::button'));

expect(cancel.getText()).toEqual('Cancel');
```